# Access client side fingerprint sensors with Blazor web assembly app

Tags: blazor, blazor-webassembly

I have access to client machine in which I install fingerprint sensor SDKs to communicate with sensors on the local network. Previously, we were using a desktop application/windows service to send commands to finger print sensors to import fingerprints, import entry time of employees etc.
Is it possible to develop a web application using Blazor web assembly to do same functionalities?

Comment: Generally, anything you can do with other web technologies, you can do with Blazor.  There are plenty of articles around the web which describe the possibilities and limitations of biometrics via web.  The first question would be to ask if the hardware vendor has support for web integration.

Comment: @Kevon i thought blazor web assembly makes client dowload dlls and thus have more accessibility to client machine, or am I wrong ?

Comment: Yes, you are wrong.  Blazor WASM still has all of the sandbox restrictions that normal web has.  It is the Browser that is the sandbox.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/?view=aspnetcore-6.0 - "WebAssembly code can access the full functionality of the browser via JavaScript, called JavaScript interoperability, often shortened to JavaScript interop or JS interop. .NET code executed via WebAssembly in the browser runs in the browser's JavaScript sandbox with the protections that the sandbox provides against malicious actions on the client machine."